# Why does a 2D array behave like a 1D array of pointers instead of a 1D array of integers?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, implicit-conversion

I have been researching and testing my knowledge in C (I am a new computer engineering student), and ran into a problem I cannot figure out.

When trying to pass a 2D array to a function, I learned that you cannot do so with dynamically allocated arrays, since the compiler needs to know array[][columns]. However, I learned that a 2D array is stored a 1D array, where the elements of each new row just follows the elements of the previous row. When I pass an array name to a function as a pointer to an array, this seems to be the case, and my code works fine. However, in the function where the 2D array is declared, it behaves as an array of pointers instead.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int *A, int* dimA) {
    for(int i = 0; i < dimA[0]; ++i) {
        for(int j = 0; j < dimA[1]; ++j) {
            printf("%3d", A[i*dimA[1] + j]);//This would work if the elements of A[] are the rows of a 2D array mapped into a 1D array
        }
    printf("\n\n");
    }
return;
}

int main(){
    int A[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    int dimA[2] = {2,2};//dimensions of the array
    int i, j; 

    for(i = 0; i < dimA[0]; ++i) {
        for(j = 0; j < dimA[1]; ++j) {
            printf("%3d", *(A[i] + j)); //This would work if the elements of A[] are pointers
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    for(i = 0; i < dimA[0]; ++i) {  //Same code as printArray function
        for(j = 0; j < dimA[1]; ++j) {
            printf("%3d", A[i*dimA[1] + j]);//This would work if the elements of A[] are the rows of a 2D array mapped into a 1D array
        }
        printf("\n\n");
    }

    printArray(A, dimA);
    return 0;
}
```

The following code outputs the array correctly in main() when the array is treated as an array of pointers, but not when treated as a 1D array of integers. However, when I pass the same array to the printArray function as a pointer, I can treat it as a 1D array of integers and it works. Any help would be appreciated (I already understand that I can instead use an array of pointers, but I really want to understand what the problem was). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When trying to pass a 2D array to a function, I learned that you cannot do so with dynamically allocated arrays, since the compiler needs to know array[][columns].

This is true, in the sense that you cannot pass *any* array to a function.  You cannot even express such a concept in C, though you can write code that looks like that to the casual eye.  In almost every context where an expression evaluating to an array appears -- including function call expressions -- the array value is replaced by a pointer to the first array element.

It is partially true in the sense that a 2D array is an array of arrays, and the dimension of the (array) element type is is part of the overall array's type, part of the type of every element, and part of the type of a pointer to the first element.  As such, that dimension must be part of the type of any function parameter to which you want to pass (a pointer to the first element of) the array.

It is most accurately characterized as false, however, even for 2D arrays both of whose dimensions are determined at run time.  Since 1999, C has supported variable-length arrays (though in C11 it was made optional), and these play very nicely indeed with dynamically-allocated multi-dimensional arrays and with pointers to arrays of varying dimension:

```
// Dynamically allocating a 2D array of runtime-determined dimensions:
unsigned rows = calculate_number_of_rows();
unsigned columns = calculate_number_of_columns();
int (*matrix)[columns] = malloc(rows * sizeof(*matrix));
```

They work well for functions accepting such pointers, too:

```
void do_something(unsigned rows, unsigned columns, int matrix[rows][columns]);
```

... or, equivalently ...

```
void do_something(unsigned rows, unsigned columns, int matrix[][columns]);
```

... or ...

```
void do_something(unsigned rows, unsigned columns, int (*matrix)[columns]);
```

Those three forms are completely equivalent.

> However, I learned that a 2D array is stored a 1D array, where the elements of each new row just follows the elements of the previous row.

A 2D array is an array of 1D arrays.  The elements of any array are stored contiguously in memory without padding, so the layout of a 2D array of dimensions (*r*, *c*) cannot be distinguished from the layout of a 1D array of dimension *r* * *c*, but I recommend against thinking of it in the terms
you used.

> When I pass an array name to a function as a pointer to an array, this seems to be the case, and my code works fine.

Do not do that.  In practice, it is very likely to work exactly as you say, but you should heed the warnings emitted by your compiler -- and it definitely should be emitting warnings about that.

> However, in the function where the 2D array is declared, it behaves as an array of pointers instead.

You've not presented an example of a function that would fit your description.  Certainly it is possible to pass an array of pointers, but it is quite possible to pass a pointer to an array instead.  See above for examples.

Answer (score 5):

According to the C Standard (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
>   operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, **an
>   expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
>   expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
>   element of the array object and is not an lvalue**. If the array
>   object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Thus in the first for loop

```
for(i = 0; i < dimA[0]; ++i) {
    for(j = 0; j < dimA[1]; ++j) {
        printf("%3d", *(A[i] + j)); //This would work if the elements of A[] are pointers
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

the expression `A[i]` has the type `int[2]`. Being converted to pointer it has the type `int *`. So for each i the expression `A[i]` points to the first element of each "row" of the array `A`.

The expression `A[i] + j` points to the j-th element of each row. So dereferencing the pointer you get j-th element of the i-th row of the array.

In the second loop

```
for(i = 0; i < dimA[0]; ++i) {  //Same code as printArray function
    for(j = 0; j < dimA[1]; ++j) {
        printf("%3d", A[i*dimA[1] + j]);//This would work if the elements of A[] are the rows of a 2D array mapped into a 1D array
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

the expression `A[i*dimA[1] + j]` has the type `int *` and points to `i *dimA[1] + j` "row" of the array that is it points beyond the array. So the loop does not make sense.

The function declared like

```
void printArray(int *A, int* dimA);
```

is called like

```
printArray(A, dimA);
```

The second argument that has the type `int[2]` is indeed converted to pointer of the type `int *` that points to the first element of the array.

As for the first argument then it is also converted to pointer to its first element. And what is the element of the array? The element of this two-dimensional array is a one-dimensional array of the type `int[2]`. So pointer to an object of this type will have type `int ( * )[2]`

Pointers `int *` and `int ( * )[2]` are not compatible and by this reason the compiler shall issue a diagnostic message.

the correct declaration of the function should look like

```
void printArray(int ( *A )[2], int *dimA);
```

Answer (score 1):

Compiling the code gives a warning that is a bit of a clue to what is going on:

```
main.c:27:27: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]
            printf("%3d", A[i*dimA[1] + j]);//This would work if the elements of A[] are the rows of a 2D array mapped into a 1D array
                    ~~~   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:32:16: warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int [2][2]' to parameter of type 'int *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    printArray(A, dimA);
               ^
main.c:3:22: note: passing argument to parameter 'A' here
void printArray(int *A, int* dimA) {
```

When you declare your array:

```
int A[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
```

this is stored as one contiguous chunk of memory, as you stated. In memory, this is equivalent to:

```
int A[4] = {1,2,3,4};
```

However, whenever you go to lookup/dereference the values, depending on the type, the compiler is implicitly doing some bookkeeping for you. For the second case:

```
int A[4] = {1,2,3,4};

A[0] = *(&A + 0) = 1
A[1] = *(&A + 1) = 2
...
```

fairly straightforward, the index is simply an offset off the base address. However, for the first case:

```
      y  x
int A[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
                     y   x
A[0][0] = *(&A + 2 * 0 + 0) = *(&A + 0) = 1
A[1][0] = *(&A + 2 * 1 + 0) = *(&A + 2) = 3
...
```

things start to look a bit confusing.

The first thing to note is that since the type is declared as an `int[2][2]`, you *must* dereference it twice. That is what the first warning is complaining about. Because it was only dereferenced once, your `int **` became an `int *`, which is not the same as an `int`.

The second thing to notice is because the type is declared as a multi-dimensional array, the compiler will do some bookkeeping for you. Since the array was being dereferenced on the first dimension, the size of the second dimension to stride to the correct location was already taken into account, so instead of `col * j + i`, you actually got `col * (col * j + i) + i`, which is not what you want!

To get the desired effect, you can either:

1. Cast `A` into an `int *`. This is what happened when you called your `printArray` function, and also why it works.
2. Access the array from the lowest dimension. Instead of saying `A[i*dimA[1] + j]`, do `A[0][i*dimA[1] + j]`. This will correctly dereference to an `int` and also effectively bypass the bookkeeping.